# Accessibility API/Component does not read the contents in Hybrid Mobile Application

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, accessibility, accessibility-api

Hybrid Mobile Application built using Cordova, BackBoneJS and JQuery mobile does not respond to Accessibility touch events.

In Accessibility mode "ON", the expectation is, the Application needs to read the contents/text in single tap and the assigned action needs to be performed on double tap. But the Hybrid Application neither reads the text nor waits for the double click. The application works as it is in normal mode.

Is there any support library available or any add-ons needs to be added ?

Comment: Just tested with basic app built by phonegap. It works as expected. It reads with single tap and button works with double tapping.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get that worked. Now, I just created a fresh Cordova Application using Cordova CLI. Added couple of labels to it. Enabled "Accessibility" and on Tap of the labels, no action got performed. Its dumb. If you have did, can you please let me know the steps ? I am using Samsung Galaxy Neo mobile device running android version 4.4.4. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry I tested with iPhone5, iOS 10. I just tested with Android 6 and it's not working as expected. In Android, it's almost unusable.

Comment: Try checking over your app with Android Device Monitor, specifically get UI Snapshot, and see what PhoneGap is doing with your view structure.

Comment: When you enable TalkBack on Android all single-finger-tap actions become double-tap. This is because TalkBack captures the single-finger tap to do its work (like enable its own context menus). Using two fingers will go to the application directly. What happens when you use two fingers to tap? And do you have a third-party plug-in / add-on in your application to try to manage accessibility?

Comment: @Joseph, use phonegap-mobile-accessibility plugin, whenever user single tap then use plugins' method "speak" to read the text then on double tap do default functionality if any using javascript